# SSRS Total including other groups

Tags: reporting-services, report, grouping, percentage, builder

I can't get the total because of the grouping. I can't explain but here are some screen shots

[image]

The Expression for the % is

```
=Sum(Fields!NonOfwCount.Value)
```

/
Count(Fields!NonOfwCount.Value) *100

Output is

[image]

As you can see, the % of Male and Female should be 50% each.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by using ReportItems, my question was stupid. A better question would have been "how to get value from textbox". I hope this helps someone